# How to add a CSS class to the tooltip on a navigation menu?

Tags: menus, title, tooltip

I'm looking for a way to add a CSS class to the anchor tag of the tooltip on a menu item. Currently, I see that you can easily add a CSS class to the menu's li but I'm trying to style the tooltip itself, not the menu item.

Looking at the [Codex for wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), I don't see an argument available to handle adding a class to the tooltip anchor.

Is there a filter I can use? How?

FYI, I'm using a plugin called [Simple Tooltips](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-tooltips/) to create the tooltips, as all it requires is that I add a class to the HTML element I want to add a tooltip to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code into your functions.php

```
class Tooltips_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(
            ' '
        ,   apply_filters(
                'nav_menu_css_class'
            ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
            )
        );

        ! empty ( $class_names )
            and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $attributes  = '';

        if(strstr($class_names, 'tooltips')) {
            $attributes  = ' class="tooltips"';
        }
        $class_names  = str_replace('tooltips', '', $class_names);

        $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>";



        ! empty( $item->attr_title )
            and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->target )
            and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->xfn )
            and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        ! empty( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

        // insert description for top level elements only
        // you may change this
        $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
            ?    esc_attr( $item->description )   : '';

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $item_output = $args->before
            . "<a $attributes title='".$description."'>"
            . $args->link_before
            . $title
            . '</a> '
            . $args->link_after 
            . $args->after;

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
        ,   $item_output
        ,   $item
        ,   $depth
        ,   $args
        );
    }
}
```

And update this  wp_nav_menu code where your menu is called from theme [ header.php ]

```
    wp_nav_menu(
                    array (
                        'menu'            => 'main-menu',
                        'container'       => FALSE,
                        'container_id'    => FALSE,
                        'menu_class'      => '',
                        'menu_id'         => FALSE, 
                        'walker'          => new Tooltips_Walker
                    )
                );
```

and use "tooltips" - as menu item class and put the description to show as tips title.

and make sure the "Zebra_Tooltip" Css class z-index is more then all element's z-index: or add this css code in style.css

```
.Zebra_Tooltip{ z-index: 100000 !important;}
```

Comment: "and use "tooltips" - as menu item class and put the description to show as tips title." - I've added "tooltips" (without quotes) as the CSS Classes and text for the Title Attribute under the Appearance > Menu screen but nothing's changed.

Comment: Did you add the code in functions.php and update the wp_nav_menu.. code in header.php ? ; Also can i have the link of your website.

Comment: Yes, all of that. The site is on a local server, sorry.

Comment: I've got it working on the default WP themes. I guess I have to figure out how to get it working on my theme. Thanks!

Comment: If you have Firebug or Google Crome browser Developer tools you may check for the Javascript error on your theme.

Comment: There was no error. I was using 'menu' => 'main-menu' when I should have been using 'menu' => 'main-sections'

Answer (score -2):

There is an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.the-perfect-life.org/html-5-css-3-php-wordpress-jquery-javascript-photoshop-illustrator-tutorial/how-to-create-custom/wordpress-plugin-theme-codex-code-function/wordpress-style-tooltip-no-plugin-css-add-a-custom-tooltip-to-any-element/)!

Comment: Link only answers are quite recommended. You could explain a bit.